# Parse server query each with useMasterKey parameter

Tags: javascript, parse-server

I'm migrating from Parse to Parse server. Most of my code is made without promises.
For this to work, I have to send the parameter: `useMasterKey: true` (where necessary) for each query / save.

For find and get queries or fetch objects, I have no problems, example:

Parse.com (find)

```
query.find({
    success: function(results) {
    //...
```

Parse Server (find)

```
query.find({useMasterKey: true
    }).then(function(results) {
    //....
```

Parse.com (fetch)

```
user.fetch({
    success: function(user) {
    //...
```

Parse Server (fetch)

```
user.fetch({useMasterKey: true,
    success: function(user) {
    //....
```

**The problem is with each functions:**

Parse.com (each)

```
query.each(function(comment) {
    //...
```

Parse Server (each)

```
query.each({useMasterKey: true
      }).then(function(comment) {
      //....
```

It does not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the [docs](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_each) don't suggest that the `useMasterKey` option is supported for an `each` query, having tested and verified myself it is in fact possible. Syntax as follows:

```
query.each(callback, {useMasterKey: true})
```

Where `callback` is a function that is called for each result of the query.

Answer (score 1):

The `each` method of a query support `useMasterKey`, it's passed as an argument after the callback function, that will be executed for each result of the query.

The syntax is:

```
query.each(function (object, error) {
        // Your function code
    }, {
        useMasterkey: true
})
```

Where `object` is a result for the query and `error` is a possible error that happened.

---

But, as shown [here](http://docs.back4app.com/docs/ios/background-jobs/), it's better to just use `useMasterKey` for when you're actually changing something in the database:

```
query.each(function (object, error) {
    object.destroy({
        success: function (object) {
            console.log("Successfully destroyed object.")
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error.code + " - " + error.message)
        },
        useMasterKey: true
   })
})
```